# Dependencies problem with x2go

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, x2go

I need help with my Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit. I can't update Ubuntu, because I always have problems with x2go. See message below:

```
dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:
  openssh-server depends on openssh-client (= 1:5.9 p1-5ubuntu1.2); however:  
  Version openssh-client 1:5.9 p1-5ubuntu1.3 is installed.
dpkg: error processing openssh-server (- configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of x2goserver:
  x2goserver depends on openssh-server; however:
  The openssh-server package is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing x2goserver (- configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of x2goserver-extensions:
  x2goserver x2goserver-dependent extensions (> ~ 842 = ~ 4.0.1.14-0 ubuntu12.04.1); however:
  X2goserver the package is not configured yet.
  x2goserver x2goserver-dependent extensions (<< 4.0.1.14-0 ubuntu12.04.1.1 ~ ~ ~ 842)
```

I think there may be a conflict between the new and old version of x2go.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the underlying issue is with the OpenSSH packages, which X2Go depends on. Specifically, it looks like openssh-client is being upgraded from p1-5ubuntu1.2 to p1-5ubuntu1.3, but openssh-server is not being upgraded from p1-5ubuntu1.2. They need to both be upgraded at the same time to the same version.

Try running "sudo apt-get update" and seeing if your still have the problem. There may have been a temporary issue with the openssh-server not update being pushed out to your ubuntu apt mirror.

You should then be able to run "sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client" without issue; that command actually upgrades those 2 packages (instead of installing them) because they're already installed. If that command works without issue, then so should "sudo apt-get upgrade". which upgrades every package on the system.

Note: I am an X2Go Developer